# Is there a way to extract .NET 2.0 from the .NET 3.5?

Tags: .net, deployment, .net-2.0, .net-3.5

.NET Framework 3.5 SP1 installs the .NET Framework 2.0 SP2 and the .NET Framework 3.0 SP2 behind the scenes. These installation packages (especially .NET Framework 2.0 SP2) are not available directly from Microsoft.

Is there a way to extract them from the .NET Framework 3.5 SP1 installation package?

Comment: Why are you trying to do this?  Some sort of support/compatibility situation?

Comment: Our application (not depending on 3.0 or 3.5) uses new methods available with the updated mscorlib. The updated mscorlib is a part of .NET 3.5 SP1.

Comment: So, what you want to do is *only* install 3.5 SP1? To keep filesize down? I wouldn't. There's a reason MS packaged them together. 3.5 SP1 may rely on new functionality in 2.0 SP2/ 3.0 SP2.

Comment: Our application must run on Windows 2000 so I have no chance to install 3.5.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Take a look on http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vs2008/bb898654.aspx or download [.NET Frameworks 2.0 SP2 and 3.0 SP2 bootstrapper packages](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=127832). These packages give you separate .NET Framework 2.0 SP2 and .NET Framework 3.0 SP2 installation packages.

Answer (score 6):

This is worth a read:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb822049.aspx

Specifically:

*"Windows Vista does not support the standalone installation of the .NET Framework version 2.0 SP2 or version 3.0 SP2. Windows 2000 does not support the .NET Framework version 3.5 SP 1, nor the standalone installation of the .NET Framework version 3.0 SP 2."*

Also - *"If your application relies on changes that shipped with .NET Framework 2.0 SP 1 or SP 2, then you can have your application target the .NET Framework 2.0 and ask your customers to download the .NET Framework 2.0 SP 1 or SP 2. However, if your application relies on new or changed functionality, it is recommended that your application target the .NET Framework 3.5 or the .NET Framework Client Profile. "*

Which does suggest there may be a standalone release at some point in the future, though your guess is as good as mine.

Also see this comment on Somasegar's blog from around the time of the beta about the background to 2.0 SP2:

http://blogs.msdn.com/somasegar/archive/2008/05/12/visual-studio-2008-and-net-fx-3-5-sp1-beta-available-now.aspx#8515404

You could unzip the dotnetfx35.exe and try and muddle your way through installing the .NET 2.0 SP2 bits on a throwaway/test machine to see if it works. The files are under wcu/dotNetFramework/dotNetfx20.

But my caveat would be wait until the official RTM or deploy the whole of 3.5SP1, you may, as Scott correctly points out, end up with an unstable and wholey unsupportable installation (specifically MS PSS).

Answer (score 5):

If they aren't available directly then there isn't an official way to install them separately and even if you were able to extract them you would end up with a very unsupported (and probably unstable) .NET environment.

Answer (score 3):

You can download SP 2 completely separately by going to [the Microsoft download site](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=5b2c0358-915b-4eb5-9b1d-10e506da9d0f&displaylang=en)

Comment: More specifically, this link is for .NET Framework 2.0 SP2. So combine that with the link in the other answer to download the .NET Framework 2.0 SP1 Installation Redistributable, and you're good to go.

Comment: .NET Framework 2.0 SP1 (x86): http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=79BC3B77-E02C-4AD3-AACF-A7633F706BA5&displaylang=en

Comment: .NET Framework 2.0 Redistributable (x86): http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?displaylang=en&FamilyID=0856eacb-4362-4b0d-8edd-aab15c5e04f5

Answer (score 1):

You could simply download the [.NET Framework 2.0 SP1](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=79BC3B77-E02C-4AD3-AACF-A7633F706BA5) (x86), the SP2 patch (directly if you can find it, the .MSP by extracting from the 3.5 SP1 installer, or the .MSP via WSUS, or by capturing the Windows Update HTTP traffic), and create a batch file which installs SP1 then SP2 on top of it with the /silent switch. No reboot required as such between the full SP1 distribution and the SP2 patch, except when files are in use before installing the SP1 runtime, which would be the case with a complete distribution anyway.

[Here](http://icelava.net/forums/thread/1042.aspx) is a procedure I also used to follow to integrate SP1 for NFX1.1 - I imagine it should work in a similar fashion for other patches too.

Comment: Oops, didn't check the link. The rest of my post still stands, though, once the proper patch package is downloaded - why the downvotes?

Comment: Maybe someone noticed the link as well?

Comment: Sorry for my downvote, but just because you *can* do something, doesn't mean you should.

Comment: I understand your position. Wouldn't use this procedure in a production environment, but my belief is that technical information shouldn't be censored by best practices and personal beliefs, just qualified by them - i.e., tell the user what they want as long as they are aware of the downsides...

Comment: I fully agree with moocha, as long as Microsoft doesn't release an official build with SP2 integrated (just to promote framework 3.5) I must do what I must do.

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft's all-inclusive get-the-framework site: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/netframework/aa731542.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vs2008/bb898654.aspx

Download Installer (Download Size: 325 MB)

Extract it with the /x switch, there is a cab file called **adtbs_sp2oob.cab**, inside it is a file called `FL_FL_NetFx20SP2_x86.exe.3643236F_FC70_11D3_A536_0090278A1BB8`, you can rename it to `NetFx20SP2_x86.exe`, If you need 64-bit, it's probably `FL_NetFx20SP2_x64.3643236F_FC70_11D3_A536_0090278A1BB8`. It should be completely independent, works OK for me so far.